# WordPress is_single do this and if is not specific single ID do that

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I need help with one post.

I have post ID: 236512

I am using function on every is_single() post, but how can continue using the function on all posts except the specific post ID?

```
<?php if(is_single() && !is_single(236512)):?>
// My regular function
<?php else: ?>
// Do nothing
<?php endif; ?>
```

Is that syntax Ok or is there any other functional way doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
if ( is_singular( 'post' ) && get_the_ID() != 236512 ) {
   //function
} else {
  //nothing
}
```

`is_single()` should do the same thing. However, you mentioned that it's a post, not any single-CPT.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you.